# How to parse this string to array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, indexing

How to parse this string with fomat as below to **array** or **anything** that can access each string by index?

```
"[\"string 1\",[\"string 2\",\"string 3\"],\"string 4\"]" // to array_1
"[[\"string 5\",\"string 6\",\"string 7\"],\"string 8\"]" // to array_2
```

Example, `array_1[1][0] == "string 2"` or `array_2[0][2] == "string 7"`
Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your expected result after parsing? how `array_1[1][0] = "string 2"`

Comment: what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Suggestion: A lot of your questions do not demonstrate any research effort. It is good practice to include a summary about what you have tried already, so we do not waste time on things you have tried already. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: If your arrays are currently in a string format, you could consider replacing the []-symbols with {}-symbols and then parse it as json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your code and got the expected results, I think your issue lies within array_2 having an extra bracket at the end of it.

```
var array_1 = ["string 1",["string 2","string 3"],"string 4"];
var array_2 = [["string 5","string 6","string 7"],"string 8"];

console.log(array_1[1][0]); // "string 2"
console.log(array_2[0][2]); // "string 7"
```

You can see it all working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/t7SDr/

**Edit**

To do this in C#, you can simply do this:

```
string[] array_1 = {"string 1",{"string 2","string 3"},"string 4"};

var stringItem = array_1[1][2];
```

Comment: JS or not, he has invalid code with the final bracket. That's the issue here.

Comment: The question was also tagged C# after it was asked, so my apologies.

Answer (score -1):

you can define and access the string array like this

```
        //to define the string array
 string[] array_1 = new string[]
                                   {
                                       "string 1",
                                       "string 2",
                                       "string 3",
                                       "string 4"
                                   };

// To access the string using foreach loop

            foreach (string str in array_1)
                Console.WriteLine(str);

       // To access the string using index

    for (int i = 0; i < array_1.Length;i++ ) 

            Console.WriteLine(array_1[i]);
```

Comment: I think OP knows how to define & index and array. He was asking how to parse the strings into an array